# Navigation Component "Back" via device reloads Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

The two screens relevant to my issue amount to `MainFragment` (a master view) and `ProfileFragment` (a detail view). The launch path from login -> main -> profile works fine. The return path isn't working as well. I get stranded at main when navigating backward with via gesture or device button.

On the initial "back" from the profile, I'm returned to main and see main's `onViewCreated`, `onResume` lifecycles. I expect back from main would return to login or even exit the app, but instead it reloads main a dozen times before crashing.

For any subsequent "back" from main, the logs reveal main's `onAttach`, `onCreate`, `onViewCreated`, `onResume` lifecycles recurring each time. This seems suspicious although it's a pretty vanilla navigation graph, a single Activity hosting four basic Fragments. They're all navigated with basic actions using their generated, type-safe `Directions` classes. I haven't overridden `onBackPressed` in any of these classes.

Combinations of `app:popUpTo="@+id/loginFragment"` and/or `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` haven't helped.

Do I need to implement back or "up" in order to work as expected? Any thoughts are appreciated.

[image: nav_graph.xml]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On closer inspection, it's working the way it's coded. Of course it is!

The preceding LoginFragment checks a SharedPreference value and navigates to main. I confirmed that happens so quickly I thought I never returned to login screen, when in fact I did.

I'll investigate removing login screen from the stack after authentication.